# PDFView getting/setting scroll position

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Good Morning,

I have a `PDFView` in an `NSSplitView`.  I've implemented zooming and scrolling, using trackpad gestures.  However whenever I reload the PDF, the scroll position resets to the top left corner.  This is ok if the full page is shown, but if the PDF is zoomed and only partly visible, this can move the section of interest out of the view.

I've tried using `enclosingScrollView` but that returns `nil`. I've tried digging through the subviews to find the `NSScrollView`, the `NSScroller`s, `NSClipView` many of the `displayRect` and related properties are readonly.  I've tried reading the `verticalPageScroll` and `verticalLineScroll`  but they only every return 10.0.

I seem to be left with systematically going through the class properties and methods of each subview and see if they contain the data.

I'm sure someone knows how to get and set this.

Thanks.
Mark

Comment: Have you tried `visibleRect` and `scrollRectToVisible:` of `NSView`?

Comment: I've just had a look at `visibleRect` and the subviews of `PDFView` and it appears that `NSClipView` has the most promising `NSRect`.  I've been looking at so many different `NSRect`s they all blended into one.  Saving the Rect from `NSClipView` modifying the document and then setting it with `scrollRectToVisible:` did the trick, thanks!